# Is any fixed element of $L^\infty(0, 1) \bar{\otimes} M$ contained in $L^\infty(0, 1) \bar{\otimes} M_0$ where $M_0$ is separable?

Tags: tensor-products, von-neumann-algebras

Suppose $M$ is a von Neumann algebra (not necessarily separable). Given any element $a \in L^\infty(0, 1) \bar{\otimes} M$, does there exist a separable subalgebra $M_0 \subseteq M$ s.t. $a \in L^\infty(0, 1) \bar{\otimes} M_0$? More generally, if I replace $L^\infty(0, 1)$ by any countably decomposable abelian von Neumann algebra (or even by any countably decomposable von Neumann algebra), is the statement above true? (It is easy to see that the result is not true if $L^\infty(0, 1)$ is replaced by an algebra that is not countably decomposable.) It is clear the result holds if $M$ is countably decomposable itself (by utilizing the GNS construction associated with faithful normal states), but it's not clear whether it is true in the general case.

Comment: The following example might be useful: Consider $L^\infty((0, 1], \lambda) \bar{\otimes} l^\infty((0, 1], discrete)$. Let $E_t$ be the projection in $l^\infty((0, 1], discrete)$ which, when represented as a function from $(0, 1]$, has value $1$ on $(0, t]$ and $0$ otherwise; for all $t \in (0, 1]$. Let $a \in L^\infty((0, 1], \lambda) \bar{\otimes} l^\infty((0, 1], discrete)$ be the element such that, when represented as a strongly measurable function $(0, 1] \rightarrow l^\infty((0, 1], discrete)$, sends $t$ to $E_t$.

Comment: The algebra generated by $E_t$ is, if I'm not mistaken, the entirety of $l^\infty((0, 1], discrete)$, which is not separable. This could potentially be counterexample, though my argument above isn't sufficient to demonstrate that.

Comment: Another illuminating example is obtained by changing the definition of $E_t$ to the rank-one projection onto the canonical basis vector at point $t$, and then defining $a$ the same way. $E_t$ still generate the entire $l^\infty((0, 1], discrete)$, but examining closely, one can actually see that $a = 0$ in the tensor product, which shows why just checking the range of $a$ as a strongly measurable function is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out myself. The statement is true iff $M$ is countably decomposable. An counterexample when $M$ is not countably decomposable is given by exactly the operator defined in my first comment, though it is somewhat complicated to prove this.